# cf curl /v2/organizations is not listing all the orgs metadata

Tags: pagination, cloud-foundry

I am trying to get the organization entity name by using **`owning_organization_guid`**. When I execute the below command, I get the required metadata of the organization:

```
cf curl /v2/organizations/<owning_organization_guid>
```

But when I execute just `cf curl /v2/organizations` and manually search for the **`owning_organization_guid`** it is not present for a few of them! For me it looks like `cf curl /v2/organizations` is not listing all the organizations' metadata.

Note: I am fetching `owning_organization_guid` by executing the command: `cf curl /v2/domains`

The issue is due to pagination, `cf curl` by default doesn't list all the domains or organizations, looks like there needs some wrapper for cf curl to fetch everything.

Could someone please help me here?

Comment: Can you take a step back and describe what exactly are you trying to do here? Especially the part where you're having trouble. Overall what info are you trying to get & why are you trying to get it this way?

Comment: @DanielMikusa, since `cf curl /v2/domains?` command doesn't list all the domains metadata, we need pagination here to get all the metadata. Currently i am looking for a wrapper for `cf curl` command in `BASH script` to help my jobs in listing all the domains and organizations metadata.

Comment: What CLI `cf version` and CAPI versions you're running?

Answer (score 1):

To paginate the output of `cf curl` with Bash, you can do something like this.

```
# requires `jq`
function load_all_pages {
    URL="$1"
    DATA=""
    until [ "$URL" == "null" ]; do
        RESP=$(cf curl "$URL")
        DATA+=$(echo "$RESP" | jq .resources)
        URL=$(echo "$RESP" | jq -r .next_url)
    done
    # dump the data
    echo "$DATA" | jq .[] | jq -s
}
```

See this gist for usage example, https://gist.github.com/dmikusa-pivotal/3dedcf87de7ed14b11556c40cf0c26cb